# Pnp powershell asking credentials again and again

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

In PnP PowerShell for SharePoint 2013 site, how to give credentials only once, so that it will not ask credentials again while connecting to different site collections coming from a CSV file input.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$SiteCollections = import-csv -path ".\Source_Destination_URLMapping.csv"

$listTitle = "variation labels" 

foreach($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections) 
{ 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteCollection.SiteUrl (get-pnplistitem -list "variation labels").count 
}
```

Comment: Can you Please share the code snippet that you are executing? Looks difficult to answer without that.

Comment: @GautamSheth  `$SiteCollections = import-csv -path ".\Source_Destination_URLMapping.csv"
$listTitle = "variation labels"

foreach($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections)
{
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteCollection.SiteUrl 
(get-pnplistitem -list "variation labels").count }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the same account has access to all the site collections in the csv file, you can simply ask the user for credentials using the `Get-Credential` method.

You can then pass these credentials to `Connect-PnPOnline` and get your data as below:

```
$SiteCollections = import-csv -path ".\Source_Destination_URLMapping.csv"

$listTitle = "variation labels" 

$creds = Get-Credential

foreach($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections) 
{ 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteCollection.SiteUrl -Credentials $creds 
    Write-Host (get-pnplistitem -list "variation labels").count 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply open PowerShell and enter this:
**Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xyz.sharepoint.com** (if you are working on subsite then you have to write full subsite address here)
after that it will simply open a popup box and it will ask to enter login credentials then login ..
After this step you don't need to login again.